# How can I set the RowKey to a new value with a sequence

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following class:

```cs
public class Note : TableServiceEntity
{
    public Note( )
    {
    }

    public Note(string pK)
    {
        PartitionKey = pK,
        RowKey = Seq.GetSequence().ToString();
    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to set the RowKey to the value generated by the sequence. Can anyone explain how to do this with a constructor? What I get is a syntax error: `Virtual member call in constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Seq
{
   static int index;
   public static int GetSequence()
   {
      return index++;
   }
}

public class Note : TableServiceEntity
{
   public Note(string partitionKey, string rowKey) 
      : base(partitionKey, Seq.GetSequence().ToString()) { }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the second parameter from the Note() constructor as this won't be needed.  Also it will still need the empty constructor as this is what will be used when it's deserialised from table storage.

Comment: Yes, the code can be re factored, but the answer is still valid as it answers her question imo. It's just some pseudo code mock-up. Thanks though.